# How to read EXT2 from Windows 7 64-bit? 

Tags: windows, filesystems

Are there any working solutions for accessing and ext2 filesystem from Windows 7?

Answer (score 9):

Ext2FSD is the best I found.

http://www.ext2fsd.com/

You define mountpoints and you can navigate the drives just like normal, without having to open another program. You can define the drives to be mounted at boot. It works with ext2 and ext3.

Comment: Worked great after one reboot!

Answer (score 8):

[Ext2 Installable File System For Windows](http://www.fs-driver.org/):

It provides Windows NT4.0/2000/XP/2003/Vista/2008 with full access to Linux Ext2 volumes (read access and write access).  When installing this software make sure you run it under Compatibility Mode; Windows Vista (Service Pack 2) should work but you can test the Compatibility system under different operating systems.

Comment: My Windows 10 hangs upon its installation.

Answer (score 6):

Use **[Ext2Read](http://ext2read.blogspot.com/)**.

> Ext2Read is an explorer like utility to explore ext2/ext3/ext4 files. It now supports LVM2 and EXT4 extents. It can be used to view and copy files and folders. It can recursively copy entire folders. It can also be used to view and copy disk and file.

[image]

[Download.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/)

**Note**: This program must be run as Administrator. Right click the file
and select run as Administrator.