# Can I access an ext4 Linux partition in Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, file-transfer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I access a Linux partition from Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/93664/how-can-i-access-a-linux-partition-from-windows)
>   [How to read EXT2 from Windows 7 64-bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/311934/how-to-read-ext2-from-windows-7-64-bit) 
>   [Does a ext4 reader for Windows exist?](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/does-a-ext4-reader-for-windows-exist)

I am currently in Windows and was wondering if there is any way I could mount my Linux partition, so I can access and transfer files? The file system is ext4

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How to read EXT2 from Windows 7 64-bit?](http://superuser.com/questions/311934/how-to-read-ext2-from-windows-7-64-bit), [Mount ext3fs in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/8298/mount-ext3fs-in-windows)

Comment: After your edit, it's: [Does a ext4 reader for Windows exist?](http://superuser.com/questions/37512/does-a-ext4-reader-for-windows-exist)

Comment: updated answer with link for ext4

Answer (score 3):

You need a driver to mount an ext2 partition, like [this one](http://www.fs-driver.org/) (not sure if this one will work on Win 7, it isn't specified, if that is important).

EDIT: to reflect slhck's comment, this will only work if you are using ext2fs/ext3fs, I can update with other options if this is not what you are using.

EDIT2: [This one](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) will work on Ext2,3,4 (0.50 and up for ext4) and will run on all modern Windows versions

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of the installable file system drivers like [this](http://www.fs-driver.org/)

Edit: In regards to using ext4. It looks like there is a patche for the ext2 [reader](http://www.socialblogr.com/2010/09/how-to-read-file-in-ext4-file-system-from-windows-7.html)

This will be read only access. And I see I'm still too slow ;)